# Short name for rearranging verb and adjective places in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

The usual "Working Hard?" greeting can be rearranged to "Hardly Working!" reply.

Is there a name for this process?
In the above statement instead of using "rearranging" can one use "permuting" instead?

Comment: Related: [“Some champagne for my real friends, some real pain for my sham friends.”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22219/some-champagne-for-my-real-friends-some-real-pain-for-my-sham-friends/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[chiasmus](http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&site=webhp&source=hp&q=define%3Achiasmus&aq=f&aqi=&aql=f&oq=&pbx=1#hl=en&site=webhp&q=chiasmus&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=bvDNTcW3AYHcgQePwdWwDA&ved=0CBYQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=4107420a6531b1ee)

Comment: +1ed it, no idea why somebody would have voted down this.

Answer (score 1):

[reshuffling](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reshuffle) (not only used for decks of cards) ?

Comment: definitely accptable as alternate to permuting. +1ed it too

Answer (score 1):

[metathesis](http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=define%3Ametathesis&aq=f&aqi=&aql=f&oq=&pbx=1#hl=en&q=metathesis&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=ke_NTY6wKJTogQfzncSvDA&ved=0CCIQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=4107420a6531b1ee)

Comment: intrestingly relavent word, although not the answer but thanks for the intrsting word. +1 it too.