# Is there a name for this kind of phrase?

Tags: idioms, expressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a name for inverting word order to accomplish a different meaning?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37513/is-there-a-name-for-inverting-word-order-to-accomplish-a-different-meaning)
>   ["Some champagne for my real friends, some real pain for my sham friends."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22219/some-champagne-for-my-real-friends-some-real-pain-for-my-sham-friends)

Is there any one similar kind of phrase here, what are they called?

For example :

> 1) Why do we park on Driveways and Drive on Parkways ?
>
> 2) Why are apartments together?

What are these phrases called?

Comment: I edited your question so it is clearer that you want the name of the phrase, and not a list of examples. Does it still make sense to you?

Comment: yes it does for some extent but i really wanted users to come with there own Chiasmus here because Chiasmus are always interesting to use in literature. I hope i answered your question

Comment: List questions are off topic. You can't ask for examples of them without your question being closed. However, now that you know the name you can look up your own examples. I just wanted to make sure my edits didn't obscure the on-topic part of your question.

Comment: Absolutely fine with me. Thanks for making me understand off-topic and on-topic part here.

Comment: You're welcome. I think this question is interesting, so I look forward to seeing more from you. Also, in the future if you want examples like this, come to chat (once you get 20 rep) and we'll be happy to think up examples.

Comment: ya sure . I am looking forward to get my 20 rep as early as possible. Thank you once again

Comment: Looks like you can join chat now!

Comment: @simchona let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1173/discussion-between-abid-and-simchona)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a [Chiasmus](http://www.bbc.co.uk/dna/h2g2/A592643):

> Chiasmus is a figure of speech where wit is conveyed through the reversal of words or phrases in clauses.

Some examples would be:

> 'Never let a fool kiss you, or a kiss fool you'
>   "Nice to see you, to see you, nice!"
>   "You forget what you want to remember, and you remember what you want to forget."

That's for your first example.

Comment: Yes that is Chiasmus. And thanks for those wonderful examples.

Comment: I found one more :) I LOVE YOU NOT BECAUSE I NEED YOU . I NEED YOU BECAUSE I LOVE YOU :)

Comment: That's a very sweet one, to keep in mind... for future use:)

Comment: @ Thursagen yeah Believe me i used it and it worked for me :)